# Grid lines appearing on top of 3d bar plot in matplotlib in Qt?

Tags: python, qt, 3d, matplotlib, gridlines

I've got a program built that successfully creates properly formatted 3D histograms based on input data when outputting directly to Matplotlib. However, when I recently tried to take the same code and output to a MatplotlibWidget inside of Qt Designer, the grid lines always show up in front of the 3D plot, unless I remove them from the figure entirely.

Good histogram:
[image: Histogram with well-behaved gridlines]
Bad histogram:
[image: Histogram with unruly gridlines]

Both are using largely identical code. I've tried changing the order of plotting different elements, tried set_axisbelow(), which has been unhelpful, and tried changing zorder, which hasn't had any apparent impact. The only thing that does work is grid(b=False), which turns the lines off entirely, but I would prefer to leave them in as it is very difficult to get an exact value from the 3D figure without them.

Here's the offending code:

```py
def plotHist(self, xVals, yVals, zVals, cVals, targetWidget):

    targetWidget.canvas.ax.clear()
    targetWidget.canvas.ax.grid(b=True, zorder=2)

    x = np.array(xVals[1:], dtype=np.float) 
    y = np.array(yVals[1:], dtype=np.float)        

    if np.max(x) !=0.0:
        x = x[np.nonzero(x)]
        y = y[np.nonzero(y)]

        histPlot = targetWidget.canvas.ax

        hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=self.binNum)

        hist = np.rot90(hist, k=3)
        hist = np.fliplr(hist)
        elements = (len(xedges) - 1) * (len(yedges) - 1)

        xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1], yedges[:-1])

        xpos = xpos.flatten()
        ypos = ypos.flatten()
        zpos = np.zeros(elements)

        xwidth = abs(xedges[0]-xedges[1])
        ywidth = abs(yedges[0]-yedges[1])

        dx = xwidth * np.ones_like(zpos)
        dy = ywidth * np.ones_like(zpos)
        dz = hist.flatten()

        xbottom = xedges[0] - xwidth*self.histPad
        xtop = xedges[-1] + xwidth*self.histPad
        ybottom = yedges[0] - ywidth*self.histPad
        ytop = yedges[-1] + ywidth*self.histPad

        histPlot.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, color='Tomato', alpha=0.8, zsort='max',zorder=1)

        histPlot.set_xlim(xbottom, xtop)
        histPlot.set_ylim(ybottom, ytop)
        histPlot.set_xticks(xedges)                        
        histPlot.set_yticks(yedges)
        histPlot.ticklabel_format(scilimits=(-3,2))
        histPlot.tick_params(labelsize='small')

    targetWidget.canvas.fig.tight_layout(pad=1, h_pad=None, w_pad=None, rect=(0,0,1,.95))
    targetWidget.canvas.draw()
```

In the `mplwidget` file for integrating with Qt Designer, I initialize the canvas thus:

```py
    self.fig = Figure(facecolor='white', edgecolor='gray', linewidth=1.0)

    # initialization of the canvas
    FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
    # we define the widget as expandable
    FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
    QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
    QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)

    # notify the system of updated policy
    FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

    self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
```

I can post the known-good segment of code if it would be helpful, but I am suspecting at this point that some of the known bugs with bar3d are manifesting themselves - although I would love to know otherwise.

If there are other pieces of code that would be useful, I will happily provide them, but I'm not sure exactly how to pare it down since the code is entirely functional in a standalone state, and only shows problems when integrated with Qt - which is difficult to capture concisely.

Comment: did you check the github page?  See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues?direction=desc&labels=mplot3d&page=1&sort=created&state=open for all the issue tagged as related to the 3D plotting.

Comment: This link: [axes.cla() in mplot3d - grid lines don't fall back.](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/750) seems largely similar to my issue, and the question author is also using matplotlib in Qt.

Comment: However, the workaround they have in there doesn't seem applicable to my case - targetWidget.canvas.ax.remove() doesn't work, and it isn't iterable as in their example. I don't understand the underlying mechanisms of 3d plotting very well to know exactly which object needs removing - could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: not really, I don't know that bit of the code well.

Comment: I have this issue too. (PyQt and matplotlib 1.42). As of now, it seems still open on https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/750.